# MVC Editor Template not binding Datetime year, month and day

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I have used a Edtor Template for a DateTime property (Birthday) which shows three dropdown lists to show Year, Month and Day. When dropdownlists are rendered, the name property of them is Birthday.Year, Birthday.Month and Birthday.Day respectivly. However they will not be binded to the Birthday property when you post the form.

DateTime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
List<SelectListItem> days = new List<SelectListItem>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    days.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = (i == Model.Day ? true : false) });
}

//Same for Month and Year with some modification

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Day, days, "<Year>")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month, months, "<Month>")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, years, "<Day>")
```

Comment: Try to use a Custom Model Binding [see here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/07/custom-model-binder-date-drop-downs-mvc.html).
I don't think that you can bind Day, Month and Year to a DateTime "automatically"

Comment: you are right, I have to create a custom model binding